Show that if $R$ is an Ordered integral domain, then for all $a\in R$ $a^2-a+1>0.$

Show that if $R$ is an Ordered integral domain, then for all $a\in R$ $$a^2-a+1>0.$$

My proof: I know that in an Integral domain $a^2-a=0\iff a=0\text{ or } 1.$
So for $a=0,1$, $a^2-a+1=1>0$.
We assume $1>0$. Note that $\forall a>1$, let $a=1+x, x>0$. Then $a^2-a+1=(1+x)^2-(1+x)+1=x^2+x+1>0$ as $x>0\implies x^2>0\implies x^2+x+1>0$.
For $1>a>0$. So $a^2>0$, $-a+1>0$.
For $a<0$, then $a^2>0$ and $-a>0$ and $+1>0$ so $a^2-a+1>0$

This seems correct to me, maybe you can regroup the positive cases altogether considering $x^2-x+1=(x-1)^2+x>0$ (since both $x$ and $x-1$ cannot be $0$ simultaneously).

@zwim Oh yes, that's much better way! Thank you!

@zwim Please avoid answering questions in the comment section. This is not how comments are supposed to be used: they should only clarify the problem. See here for more information. Please post answers as answers.

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.
